# Source compiled php fatal PDO Exception; could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I built Apache2.4, php 7.1.2, MySQL from source. All seem to work well, except When I try to connect to the database.
I get "faral error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in .....

In php.ini config, all the extension line ends with .dll and none has .so, I have tried almost all suggestions from around but none seems to help.

From what I learnt, I need php_mysql.so extension which I looked in my php extension folder **/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20160303/** only to find **opcahe**.so

I hope for one with this module to please share theirs with me or anyone with knowledge of how to fix it.
I use Ubuntu 17

Comment: You could try to install the php_mysql-extension. :) On Ubuntu: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install php-mysql`. When it's installed, restart Apache: `sudo apache2ctl restart` and try your code again.

Comment: Php, MySQL Apache we're installed to a custom directory, where does this extension install to

Comment: It should be handled automatically. You should be able to see where if you run phpinfo() though. Btw. You might need to install `php7.0-mysql` or `php7.1-mysql` instead, depending on your php-version.

Answer (score 0):

After a long night of searching I found what the cause was, it turned out that I should have provided some few argument with configure. So here is what I did.

./configure  --with-apxs2=/my_apache_home/bin/apxs --with-apxs2 --with-pdo-mysql --with-apxs2=/where_i_want_to_install_php --with-config-file-path=/my_php_root_dir

The issue was because I ommited with-pdo-mysql